# Class 'Memcached' not found

Tags: session, laravel, memcached

I just started using Homestead after unsuccessfully trying to get "memcached" to work on my Windows 8 machine using the inbuilt pHP server that comes with Laravel, with Homestead it work without me having to do anything but now I have moved my application online to my VPS server (Linux) and I keep getting this error:

```
"Class "Memcached" not found"
```

I have never used this session driver so this whole **memcached** topic is pretty new to me. How can I fix this issue and get my application to run normally on my web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached is an optional package (installed by default in Homestead). In Ubuntu, you can typically do `sudo apt-get install php5-memcached` to install the package. See http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php for details on other systems - I haven't installed it on Windows.

Note that you'll need a memcached *server* too, though. You may be better off with a simpler session driver, like the `file` one. You only really need `memcached`/`redis` if you're running a multiple-webserver cluster that needs shared sessions.

Comment: That would totally bum me out if it were true, because i asked a question concerning how i could make my application work much faster while avoiding as many database calls as possible and all the answers i got suggested i used memcached redis, spent hours on a very slow internet connection installing virtual box and homestead and even more hours restructuring my application.

Comment: Using `memcached` instead of `file` for *sessions* likely won't speed anything up. Using it to cache the results of database calls can be helpful, but chances are there are many other steps to take first - more efficient code, using Eloquent's eager-loading, etc. Don't expect it to be a magic fix.

Comment: Okay, now i have to revert my entire application back to the way it was before, guess i shouldn't really accept and implement answers without fully understanding them first. -_-

Comment: @user3718908 A few things. First, start using something like Git. "Revert my entire application back to the way it was before" is as easy as "git checkout master" if you're using version control. Check out https://try.github.io/ for tutorials. Second, yes, you'll want to figure out what the actual cause of slowness is. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar can be very helpful for that, as it can help you figure out *which* part of your app is causing slow-downs.

Comment: This was the post i made, all info is there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650582/building-a-cart-with-laravel-and-angular

Comment: @user3718908 This is where the debugbar can really come in handy. Install it and take a look at the Queries tab. It'll look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7GCLk.png You can see in mine only about 1ms is spent in the database. See if your database calls are *actually* the cause before trying to optimize them.