# Class 'Memcached' not found in Laravel Elastic Beanstalk App

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a laravel 6 project to an amazon elastic beanstalk application. It's running php7.3.

During 
`eb deploy`

> ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.

Looking at logs I see that it cannot find the class 'Memcached'

> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

```
 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'Memcached' not found

at /var/app/ondeck/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php:69
  65|      * @return \Memcached
  66|      */
  67|     protected function createMemcachedInstance($connectionId)
  68|     {
> 69|         return empty($connectionId) ? new Memcached : new Memcached($connectionId);
  70|     }
  71| 
  72|     /**
  73|      * Set the SASL credentials on the Memcached connection.

Exception trace:

1   Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector::createMemcachedInstance()
    /var/app/ondeck/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php:48

2   Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector::getMemcached([], [])
    /var/app/ondeck/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php:21
```

The instances are running Amazon Linux  2.9.

I have also added a config file to install memcache using the packages.
it's `.ebextensions/memcache_installer.cfg.yml`
with the following content:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    memcached: [] 
    php-pecl-memcached: []
```

The error still doesn't go away. They do however get installed because if i try to install them from within the instance I get the package is already installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class 'Memcached' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783779/class-memcached-not-found)

Comment: did you find an answer to this? we are having the same issue after moving from the amazon linux 7.2 to 7.3 ebs image

Comment: No ended up using 7.2..

Comment: Interesting... it seems like something has changed drastically from the PHP 7.1 -> PHP 7.3 AMI.

Answer (score 1):

We solved it (at least on our repo). Remove the `php-pecl-memchached` because the amazon yum version has php 5 as a dependency (we saw this in the error logs).

What we added to our `.ebextensions`:

`memcached.config`:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    memcached: []
container_commands:
  01_memcached_start:
    command: "/sbin/service memcached restart"
```

`elasticache_01.config`

```
files:
  "/tmp/AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-2.0.1-PHP73.tar.gz" :
    mode: "000777"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    source: http://elasticache-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/ClusterClient/PHP-7.3/latest-64bit
```

`elasticache_02.config`:

```
commands:
  01unzip:
    command: "tar -zxvf /tmp/AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-2.0.1-PHP73.tar.gz -C /usr/lib64/php/7.3/modules"
files:
  /etc/php.d/project.ini:
    content: |
      extension=amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so
    group: ec2-user
    mode: "000644"
    owner: ec2-user
```